# Generate span content based on 'data-title' attr from array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I have no idea what I am doing.

I am using (latest version(5.x)) swiper.js. I have multiple swipers on one page that all share the exact same options. Of course, I can initialize multiple sliders though I find that to be unnecessary since one initialization works for all of them. Also for giggles I tried to implement them now using the recommended methods and it didn't work, anyway:

Each swiper slide has a data-title attribute which I want to use as the data for generated span elements within the options of swiper.js. These generated span elements go in another div (see code).

For some reason however, in the renderbullet option, the span texts that gets created reuses the first swiper's attributes and applies the title array to all the other swipers. My understanding is that the array starts and stops in the first swiper, and uses that stored array as data for the rest. I do not desire this.

I have tried a number of methods to get the data-title attribute text to be correct but without success.

The closest I got was map(); which told me there was 21 arrays which was correct. however when I tried to use the data, each span had all 21 titles. Some help with this would be much appreciated.

Please see the code I have below:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_A0">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_A1">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">
        <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
      <span class="className">The Title_A0</span>
      <span class="className">The Title_A1</span>
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>


<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_B0">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_B1">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
      <span class="className">The Title_A0</span> <!-- I want <span class="className">The Title_B0</span>-->
      <span class="className">The Title_A1</span> <!-- I want <span class="className">The Title_B1</span>-->
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

    pagination: {
        renderBullet: function (className, title) {
            var title = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').getAttribute('data-title');
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + title + '</span>';
        },
    }
    
});
```

Comment: In the function you run `function (className, title) ` but just below you create a variable called title. is there a reason why you have both titles?

Comment: without it I get `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).getAttribute is not a function at t.renderBullet `

Comment: `var title = document.....` yields an array, therefore *Uncaught TypeError*. Rename to `titleList` and use as `titleList[0]`. To reference the `data-*` attribute, use `titleList[0].dataset.title` (indeed without `data-`). Will also run into an error when the array is emtpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this `var title = $(this.$el).find('.swiper-slide').eq(index).attr("data-title");`

It will use `$(this.$el)` as the container and then you can find the `swiper-slide` and get the `data-title`.

This should work no matter how many you have.

*Note:* in the code i have disabled `'+className+'` because it makes it hard to see the text `'<span class="'+className+'">' + title + '</span>'`

**Demo**

```js
var menu = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3']
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function(index, className) {
      var title = $(this.$el).find('.swiper-slide').eq(index).attr("data-title");
      return '<span class="">' + title + '</span>';
      //return '<span class="'+className+'">' + title + '</span>';
    },
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_A0">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_A1">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
    <span class="className">The Title_A0</span>
    <span class="className">The Title_A1</span>
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>


<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_B0">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="The Title_B1">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
    <span class="className">The Title_A0</span>
    <!-- I want <span class="className">The Title_B0</span>-->
    <span class="className">The Title_A1</span>
    <!-- I want <span class="className">The Title_B1</span>-->
    <!-- GENERATED SPAN GOES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @Carsten I wonder if you would be able to help me as well,
My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956207/swiper-js-slider-not-working-on-a-dynamic-content

Answer (score 2):

Obviously in this line:

```
var title = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').getAttribute('data-title');
```

you select ALL elements with class '.swiper-slide' , when you use getAttribute on multiple elements it will return the first occurance, which is exactly the behaviour you describe.

looking at [swiper docs for pagination](https://swiperjs.com/api/#pagination)

it states that the first parameter is the index of the current iteration.
so I use Jquery to demonstrate how you could select the correct title

```
renderBullet: function (index, className) {
    var title = $('.swiper-slide').eq(index).attr('data-title');
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + title + '</span>';
}
```

this only works when there is one slider! As you have multiple sliders you need to add a individual class or id to be able to use a selector thats selecting the correct, for example:

```
var title = $('#swiper1 .swiper-slide').eq(index).attr('data-title');
...
```

this is blind coded pseudo-code to help you with my understanding of the problem, all further is up to you good luck!

Comment: Hi @John Smith, i wonder if you would like to help me in my question, it's also related to swiper js renderBullet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956207/swiper-js-slider-not-working-on-a-dynamic-content